# Subdirect product - terminology

Tags: universal-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be algebras of the same type such that the set of all their subdirect products consists of their ordinary product alone. Is there any terminology that describes this situation? I mean something like "we say that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint/orthogonal/...".

Comment: This seems like an interest notion. Do you have an examples of this?

Comment: I have not heard of a name for this.  Is this equivalent to A, B, and AxB all being subdirectly irreducible?  If you were building a matroid, you might use matroid terminology for this relationship.  Gerhard "Hasn't Done This For Years" Paseman, 2016.07.08.

Answer (score 2):

Libor Barto and Marcin Kozik invented (and subsequently proved many results about) a concept called "absorption," which doesn't exactly give the new terminology you asked for, but does give special conditions under which a subdirect product must be the full product.

In particular, they prove the main Absorption Theorem which states that (in a Taylor variety) if $A$ and $B$ are "absorption-free," then any "linked" subdirect product of $A\times B$ is the full product.  I'm leaving out many details and all the definitions, but you can get them direct from [the source](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~barto/Articles/lmcs_arXive.pdf). (See especially Theorem 2.3.)